# How to create a NSArray of two valueForKey elements of an object from another array

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsobject

I would like to create an NSArray of NSStrings that is a concatinated value of two elements from a NSDictionary found in my original NSArray. A bit complicated I know but I feel I am almost halfway there and will describe where I am up too.

So I have a NSArray of NSDictionaries, the NSDictionaries look like this -

```
NAME 
NICK NAME
YEAR
LEGAL
```

I would like to take the Name and Nick name values of each dictionary and form them into an NSArray of NSStrings that look like this

```
Name (Nick Name)
```

but I am at abit of a loss on how to do this properly I have gotten as far as a For loop lol

```
 for (int i = [dataArrayOfDictionaries count]; i <= [dataArrayOfDictionaries count]; i++) {

    }
```

My main questions are, how do I access these Name and Nick Name element of each NSDictionary object of the array.

Then how do I put them into a formatted string like the example above and put them into their own NSArray

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to grab the name and nick name from each dictionary that you have stored in an array and then combine the two and put them in a new array? Try something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *yourNewMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(NSDictionary *dict in dataArrayOfDictionaries)
{
    NSString *realName = [dict objectForKey:@"NAME"];
    NSString *nickName = [dict objectForKey:@"NICK NAME"];

    NSString *combined = [[[realName stringByAppendingString:@" ("]stringByAppendingString:nickName]stringByAppendingString:@")"];
    [yourNewMutableArray addObject:combined];
}
```

Comment: cool will try this out.. and yes from your explanation that's exactly what I am looking to do.

Comment: word. i just edited it to change from nsmutabledictionary to nsdictionary cuz i think thats what your using?

Comment: cool so i have just tried it but i am getting this weird error on this line ** NSString *realName = [dict objectForKey@"NAME"];** which says this **Expected ']'**

Comment: oh yeah your missing a colon before the @

Comment: or my bad actually.. I WAS haha... typing out on the fly, just edited it

Comment: just broke my app so give me some time and i will mark you as correct once i fix this broken bit lol... thanks though. :P

Comment: works perfect! I forgot to remove the space between nick name :P thanks very much for the help though :)